# gcc include source files in subdirectory relative to each other in c

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, bluez

I'm having issues compiling some c code.

I have a code structure like the following

- main.c
- src

  - line

    - line.h
    - line.c

Available here: https://github.com/Vafilor/c_includes

`main.c` includes `#include "src/line/line.h"`

`src/line/line.c` includes `#include "src/line/line.h"`

When I try to compile this with `gcc main.c src/line/line.c` on ubuntu 20.4

I get this error

```
src/line/line.c:1:10: fatal error: src/line/line.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "src/line/line.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

**How can I get this to compile?**

Additional info:

I've been looking at the bluez code at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/
and they have something similar with

- `client/main.c` - includes shell.h
- `src/shared/shell.c` - includes shell.h
- `src/shared/shell.h`

so I'm trying to figure out how it works for their code base.

Comment: The usual way to do this is to pass an include directory to gcc and then have all the `#include` statements relative to that. `gcc -I src ....` and then in source code have `#include "line/line.h"`.

Comment: @kaylum That did it! I ran ```gcc -I ./ main.c src/line/line.c``` and it compiled. What you said makes sense about including src instead of the current directory and I think that's the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: OT: regarding: *When I try to compile this with gcc main.c src/line/line.c on ubuntu 20.4*  this is NOT a compile statement.  Rather this is compile two files, then link.  Also, this does not enable any warnings, except the defaults.  suggest using: `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 <name of file to compile.c >  -o <name of file to compile.o`  Then, after obtaining a clean compile for each source file:  `gcc main.o line.o -o myexec`